# How do I have url-loader resolve when not in root directory

Tags: webpack

I have a project that uses a gradle task to run webpack and outputs the files into `src/main/resources/static/webpack`, this means when hosted the files are in `https://localhost:8080/webpack`. I am using url-loader to load the files but one is too big so it is outputted to the folder as well so we end up with...

1. bundle.js
2. [hash].png

When I got to `http://localhost:8080/webpack/[hash].png` I see the image but I have a CSS file that references it and it says...

> background-image: url(17841a68afd424aec5d826632c14f3c9.jpg);

So I am assuming I just need to add a `webpack/` before in the url. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it needed `publicPath: './webpack/'` in my webpack.config...

```
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/main/resources/static/webpack'),
  publicPath: './webpack/'
},
```